# Where to download IE9 as an executable and not as an installer from the web

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am looking for an executable for IE9.
I have a PC that is not able to connect onto an internet network, and would need it updated to IE9. So essentially I need an executable file I will transfer over using a USB flash drive and install it / update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some direct downloads for the installers, as follows:

For x86: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/B/C3BF2EF4-E764-430C-BDCE-479F2142FC81/IE9-Windows7-x86-enu.exe

For x64: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/1/6/C167B427-722E-4665-9A40-A37BC5222B0A/IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe

Comment: When you run these executable's doesn't it ask to connect to the internet to do the installation?

Answer (score 0):

go to this link and click on download button on to your right side

http://www.microsoft.com/india/windows/ie/ie9.aspx